Вывод None в python
Видел похожие вопросы, однако не могу понять почему у меня такая же дилема.
def even_check(func):
    def check(*args):
        num = func(*args)
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print("even:", num)
        else:
            print("odd:", num)
    return check

@even_check
def SummaryNumber(*_property):
    num = 0
    for x in _property:
        num += x
    return num

print(SummaryNumber(1, 1, 1, 1))

Не вижу в этом коде лишних выводов, однако в терминале вывод None. Или же дело в условии, что если одно условие не подошло, то будет совершать команду print из этого блока условия?

Функция check ничего не возвращает, в ней нет return, поэтому и even_check вернёт None.

print("even:", num) -> return f"even: {num}"

@MBo есть предположения как мне без использования check() передать аргументы в метод func?

Уберите декоратор @even_check и тогда check не будет использоваться. Вы что хотите то в итоге чтобы было, какое поведение? Или наоборот, уберите print из вызова функции SummaryNumber, оставьте только сам вызов SummaryNumber(1, 1, 1, 1)
